# Shanghai math -- what is it, and how good is it?

Tags: textbooks, primary-education, interactive-teaching

Some schools in the UK are [adopting](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/05/world/asia/china-textbooks-britain.html) English translations of a grade school math textbook from Shanghai. The book appears to be designed to work with a specific teaching approach, the only specifics given in the NY Times article being:

- Students explain concepts to other students.
- The class doesn't move forward until everyone understands.

Does anyone have any more detailed info, such as sample pages? Opinions or data on how well this works compared to standard modes of instruction in the UK and US? Is it similar to what we refer to at the college level as "active learning" or "active engagement?"

Comment: from a couple paragraphs in: "Western classrooms have adopted mathematics teaching techniques from Asia before. In the past, a small number of schools in the West experimented with a Singapore-style approach. It is similar to the method used in Shanghai, which is seen as having the best math teachers in China." So, I have some knowledge in that my wife has used Singapore Math with my kids the past few years. The classic version, before common core reboot. Basically, it's not a radical reformat of teaching style in as much as I can see. The difference is with curriculum...

Comment: In particular, it's accelerated. My kids are doing things a few grades ahead of their US counterparts. But, the other main theme is integration in the sense that there is algebra early on and it gradually builds to what we might call Algebra I. Every grade has trigonmetry as well, starting from basic to eventual treatment of sines and cosines. The idea of a separate algebra or trig class doesn't make sense. It's a coherent grade by grade ratcheting of all your favorite math we need for physics etc. Also, there is some statistics stuff, but, I pay less mind to that :)

Comment: At least in the US, "Singapore Math" is a trademark, so all other math curricula need to come up with some other catchy name.

Comment: See http://cathyduffyreviews.com/homeschool-reviews-core-curricula/math/math-grades-k-6/singapore-math-primary-mathematics for a much more in-depth breakdown of the Singapore math curriculum